# I need a shape of glass in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-shapes

This may be very strange question. but this is what i need. 
I have somehow created a range slider which fills a shape with color upon sliding from value 0 to 100. [Here is the current state](http://shb.change3dev.com/questions.php) (please slide the Question#1)

The shape I created was an egg shape.(lol). I need to make it looks like a Glass. So while changing the slider range, it should seem a glass is filling with something.

Any idea on how to make a glass shape in CSS?

This is how I made the egg shape:

```css
.right {
  width: 126px;
  height: 180px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  left: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 63px 63px 63px 63px / 108px 108px 72px 72px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50% / 60% 60% 40% 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="right"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the specific type of glass you need, but essentially it all boils (ha!) down to the same idea — use [pseudo elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) for extra visuals. Let's make this basic shape:

[image: Example wine glasses]

It can even be animated with CSS3 animation:

[image: Animated fill]

In this example:

- the glass is made from the divs border and the div is made `position: relative`.
- the stem is made from `:before` and positioned with `position: absolute` and `left` / `top`
- the base is made from `:after` and positioned with `position: absolute` and `left` / `top`

### Basic Example

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 20px;
}
div:before {
  height: 100%;
  width: 1px;
  background: #000;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  top: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
div:after {
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  background: #000;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -20px;
  top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
.two {
  border-width: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 50% 50%;

}
.two:before {
  width: 6px;
  margin-left: -3px;
}
.two:after {
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
  left: -6px;
  background: #F00;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 6px #000;
  border-top: none;
  -webkit-animation: fillGlass 3s infinite;
  animation: fillGlass 3s infinite;
  border-radius: 0 0 50px 50px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fillGlass {
  0% {
    height: 25px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 46px;
    }
  100% {
    height: 25px;
  }
}
@keyframes fillGlass {
  0% {
    height: 25px;
  }
  50% {
    height: 46px;
    }
  100% {
    height: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="two">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks misterManSam. That is very very helpful :)

Comment: No worries :) also check out the basic filling CSS animation I just added.

Answer (score 0):

if u Need Magnifying Glass then here is your answer. [JS](http://jsfiddle.net/ParthAkbari/7j9vbbqa/)

**CSS**

```
.right {
 font-size: 10em;
/* This controls the size. */
display: inline-block;
width: 0.4em;
height: 0.4em;
border: 0.1em solid red;
position: relative;
border-radius: 0.35em;
}
.right::before {
  content:"";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -0.25em;
  bottom: -0.1em;
  border-width: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 0.35em;
  height: 0.08em;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 }
```

Comment: Sorry Parth. i dont mean magnifying glass :( BUT, THANK YOU for sharing this resource.

Comment: You could've simply add a comment with this link -------> http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ ........rather than copying the exact same code from there and not even citing your source.